# Округление float числа в php

Tags: php

Сейчас делаю пересчет валюты на сайте. И столкнулся с такой проблемой: цена в долларах США считается так

```
$price = (float)$price/$rate;
```

получается что-то примерно такое <b>Цена: $ 120.361445783</b>. Как мне сделать так, чтобы цена имела вид ***$ 120.36*** ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$price = round((float)$price/$rate, 2);
```

[Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.round.php)